# Rewrite a double loop in a nicer and maybe shorter way

Tags: python, loops

I am wondering if the following code can be written in a somewhat nicer way. Basically, I want to calculate `z = f(x, y)` for a `(x, y)` meshgrid.

```
a = linspace(0, xr, 100)                                                                  
b = linspace(0, yr, 100)                                                                  

for i in xrange(100):
   for j in xrange(100):
      z[i][j] = f(a[i],b[j])
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yeah. Your code as presented in the question is nice.

Do not ever think that few lines is "nice" or "cool". What counts is clarity, readability and maintainability. Other people should be able to understand your code (and you should understand it in 12 months, when you need to find a bug).

Many programmers, especially young ones, think that "clever" solutions are desirable. They are not. And that's what is so nice with the python community. We are much less afflicted by that mistake than others.

Comment: I upvoted this because it's a lesson that I'm learning myself but if they're just lists then I think that my solution is nicer than OP's code because it sidesteps extraneous iterators. With the same assumptions, wheatie's answer is better yet.

Comment: The iterators are still there. It doesn't sidestep anything. That said I use list comprehensions all the time, of course, but if I have to nest them I expand them instead, so they get easier to read.

Answer (score 8):

you could do something like

```
z = [[f(item_a, item_b) for item_b in b] for item_a in a]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html)' product:

```
[f(i,j) for i,j in product( a, b )]
```

and if you really want to shrink those 5 lines into 1 then:

```
[f(i,j) for i,j in product( linspace(0,xr,100), linspace(0,yr,100)]
```

To take it even further if you want a function of `xr` and `yr` where you can also preset the ranges of 0 and 100 to something else:

```
def ranged_linspace( _start, _end, _function ):
    def output_z( xr, yr ):
        return [_function( i, j ) for i,j in product( linspace( _start, xr, _end ), linspace( _start, yr, _end ) )]
    return output_z
```

Comment: It should be noted that all of these solutions produce a one-dimensional list instead of a nested list like OP's solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you set it all at once, you can use a list comprehension;

```
[[f(a[i], b[j]) for j in range(100)] for i in range(100)]
```

If you need to use a `z` that's already there, however, you can't do that and your code is about the neatest you'll get.

*Addition:* I don't know with what this `lingrid` does, but if it produces a 100-element list, use aaronasterling's list comprehension; no point in creating an extra iterator if you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

This shows the general result. `a` is made into a list 6-long and `b` is 4-long. The result is a list of 6 lists, and each nested list is 4 elements long.

```
>>> def f(x,y):
...     return x+y
... 
>>> a, b = list(range(0, 12, 2)), list(range(0, 12, 3))
>>> print len(a), len(b)
6 4
>>> result = [[f(aa, bb) for bb in b] for aa in a]
>>> print result
[[0, 3, 6, 9], [2, 5, 8, 11], [4, 7, 10, 13], [6, 9, 12, 15], [8, 11, 14, 17], [10, 13, 16, 19]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the one line code that you looking for

```
z =  [[a+b for b in linspace(0,yr,100)] for a in linspace(0,xr,100)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `linspace` actually looks like it could be [`np.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy-linspace). If it is you could operate on the numpy arrays without having to iterate explicitly:

```
z = f(x[:, np.newaxis], y)
```

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.linspace(0, 9, 10)
>>> y = np.linspace(0, 90, 10)
>>> x[:, np.newaxis] + y  # or f(x[:, np.newaxis], y)
array([[  0.,  10.,  20.,  30.,  40.,  50.,  60.,  70.,  80.,  90.],
       [  1.,  11.,  21.,  31.,  41.,  51.,  61.,  71.,  81.,  91.],
       [  2.,  12.,  22.,  32.,  42.,  52.,  62.,  72.,  82.,  92.],
       [  3.,  13.,  23.,  33.,  43.,  53.,  63.,  73.,  83.,  93.],
       [  4.,  14.,  24.,  34.,  44.,  54.,  64.,  74.,  84.,  94.],
       [  5.,  15.,  25.,  35.,  45.,  55.,  65.,  75.,  85.,  95.],
       [  6.,  16.,  26.,  36.,  46.,  56.,  66.,  76.,  86.,  96.],
       [  7.,  17.,  27.,  37.,  47.,  57.,  67.,  77.,  87.,  97.],
       [  8.,  18.,  28.,  38.,  48.,  58.,  68.,  78.,  88.,  98.],
       [  9.,  19.,  29.,  39.,  49.,  59.,  69.,  79.,  89.,  99.]])
```

But you could also use `np.ogrid` instead of two `linspace`:

import numpy as np

```
>>> x, y = np.ogrid[0:10, 0:100:10]
>>> x + y  # or f(x, y)
array([[ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90],
       [ 1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91],
       [ 2, 12, 22, 32, 42, 52, 62, 72, 82, 92],
       [ 3, 13, 23, 33, 43, 53, 63, 73, 83, 93],
       [ 4, 14, 24, 34, 44, 54, 64, 74, 84, 94],
       [ 5, 15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85, 95],
       [ 6, 16, 26, 36, 46, 56, 66, 76, 86, 96],
       [ 7, 17, 27, 37, 47, 57, 67, 77, 87, 97],
       [ 8, 18, 28, 38, 48, 58, 68, 78, 88, 98],
       [ 9, 19, 29, 39, 49, 59, 69, 79, 89, 99]])
```

It somewhat depends on what you're `f` is. If it contains functions like `math.sin` you need to replace them by `numpy.sin`.

If it's not about `numpy` then you should stick either with your option or optionally using `enumerate` when looping:

```
for idx1, ai in enumerate(a):
   for idx2, bj in enumerate(b):
      z[idx1][idx2] = f(ai, bj)
```

This has the advantage that you don't need to hardcode your `range` (or `xrange`) or use the `len(a)` as input. But in general if there is not a huge performance difference <sup>1</sup> then use the method you and others using your code will understand easily.

---

<sup>1</sup> If your `a` and `b` are `numpy.array`s then there would be a significant performance difference because numpy can process the arrays much faster if no `list`<->`numpy.array` conversions are required.